# azure api app (tomcat) edit server.xml by kudu

Tags: java, azure, azure-api-apps, kudu

Thank for people in stackoverflow I can keep working on new stuffs.

Thank you very much.

Anyway this is my question.

I deployed Java API app in azure app service not the Tomcat in marketplace.

So I tried to edit "Server.xml" file for configuration, but it's denied, 
"could not write to local resource"
seems like I don't have right to edit it... if i see other people's blog, they could just write, delete their files.

Do I need other extensions? Or is there any way to get ROOT permission?

Answer (score 2):

As I known, you have no permission for operating anything under the path `D:\`, besides the path `D:\home`.

If using Tomcat which not from marketplace, the Tomcat path is `D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-X.0.X` which can't be operated by user role and get the administrator permission.

However, creating App with Tomcat from marketplace, Tomcat will exists at the path `D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin` which you have the write permission.

There is an offical article [`Upload a custom Java web app to Azure`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/) which you can refer to to know how to configure Tomcat.

Comment: Thank you very much but can i use load balancer when i used Tomcat in martketplace?

Comment: @MyoungsoKang Ofcourse, you can. It doesn't matter with Tomcat from where.